# Clear tmux status bar completely

Tags: tmux, tmux-plugin-manager

I have been messing around with my tmux status bar and have behavior I don't know how to explain.  I wish to clear the entire status bar and start layering it step by step, to understand what each piece does. I do the following:

[image]
Where are the boxes with question marks coming from, and how do I get rid of them?

I have disabled all my tmux plugins and started a new session but to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like those are UTF-8 characters in `window-status-format` and `window-status-current-format` or `window-status-separator`.

Comment: Ugh, I had changed `window-status-format` and `window-status-separator`, but not `window-status-current-format`. Thank you! Will accept when timer has passed.